# ARM GCC + Cortex M4: Calling address as function generates BLX instead of BL

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, rtos, thumb

I build as little OS for a CortexM4 CPU which is able to receive compiled binaries over UART and schedule them dynamically. I want to use that feature to craft a testsuite which uploads test programs being able to directly call OS functions like memory allocation without doing a SVC. Therefor I need to cast the fixed addresses of those OS routines to function pointers. Now, casting of memory addresses resulting in wrong / non-thumb instruction code - `BL` is needed instead of `BLX`, resulting in HardFaults.

```
void (*functionPtr_addr)(void);
functionPtr_addr = (void (*)()) (0x0800084C);
```

This is the assembly when calling this function

```
 8000838:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (8000848 <idle+0x14>)
 800083a:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
 800083c:   4798        blx r3
```

Is there a way to force the BL instruction for such a case? It works with inline assembly, I could write macros but it would be much cleaner do it this way.

The code gets compiled and linked, among other things, with
`-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb`.

Toolchain:

`gcc version 12.2.0 (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.2.MPACBTI-Bet1 (Build arm-12-mpacbti.16))`

Comment: In order to know the right instruction to generate, the compiler must know the mode the target code is expected to run in (Thumb or Arm). In your case of "dynamic" code loading it has no way of knowing it. You will have to tell it explicitly (asm/inline asm whatsoever)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: With the `blx` instruction, the mode is determined by the low bit of the target address.  So it doesn't necessarily have to be known by the compiler.

Comment: @NateEldredge You are right. It have been a while I dealt closely with it..

Comment: on so we have seen this problem before and worse the user trying to adjust the address to help, and depending on the instruction/code generated it can hurt.  If you want a specific instruction, use assembly language, for connecting library or other code in this manner for this architecture, I would control all of that by using my own function call and  then I could use bx or blx and orr with one myself.

Comment: you can bl to your trampoline function with the address of the library call in a register, then bx that register and it handles both the called address and the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bl` instruction is limited in range. The compiler does not know where your code will be placed so it can't know if the instruction `bl` can be used.

> resulting in HardFaults.

The address passed to `blx` has to be odd on Cortex-M4 uCs to execute the code in the Thumb mode. Your address is even and the uC tries to execute ARM code not supported by this core.